# How to create complex nifi processor for plc?

Tags: maven, apache-nifi, plc

I want to create a custom nifi processor, so I can read s7 plc data. To do this, I want to convert the java code of this project: https://github.com/s7connector/s7connector to a nifi processor.

So, I have download mvn package type, as this webiste tells to do: 
https://medium.com/hashmapinc/creating-custom-processors-and-controllers-in-apache-nifi-e14148740ea

The problem is that s7 java code is too complex compared with the example on the web, so... How can I transform this java code to nifi processor?

Has someone a more complex code example of how to transform java to nifi processor?

Thanks!

Comment: you don't need to convert code. just use this library in a controller/processor. i have no experience with s7. however the code from https://github.com/s7connector/s7connector you could use in ExecuteGroovyScript just download the s7 library before running it.

Comment: But how can i execute it, as this java source has no java jar file...

Comment: `Maven directions` informs where [jar located](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.s7connector/s7connector/2.1). btw you could use `@Grab(group='com.github.s7connector', module='s7connector', version='2.1')` at first line of groovy script to download jar automatically.

Comment: But to.do this I need internet connection all time?? I will do not have internet on production environment

Comment: then just download it and put into lib directory

Comment: As it is a driver to connect to PLC that i hace to put on  executegroovyscript processor, can i put as the start of the flow?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't related to creating a processor but PLC4X (The universal protocol adapter for Industrial IoT) has created nar file for the Apache NiFi. Which you can use it for your end goal.

Steps:

- Download the nar file [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.plc4x/plc4j-nifi-plc4x-nar/0.7.0)
- Put it in the lib directory
- Restart the NiFi instance
- Then use PLC4XSource processor to read values. For modbus you may set "modbus:tcp://10.0.2.238:502?slave=1" as connetion string and "test1=holding-register:1" as address string. Then attribute "test1" will contain holding-register 1's value. You may get detailed info about S7 [here](https://plc4x.apache.org/users/protocols/s7.html).